# How can I host an iOS IPA (Enterprise App) on a SharePoint Site?

Tags: ios, xcode, sharepoint, ipa

I have uploaded my ipa file, manifest.plist file,  to my share point account.
but whenever I used to click on

Sharepoint url (https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/DropFile/Shared%20Documents/xxxx%20App/iOS/manifest.plist)

nothing is happening.
But if I did same thing using Dropbox, The app is installing successfully.
how can I achieve same thing using Share point.

please let me know required urls if any.